# How to locate twitter login button using Watir and Ruby?

Tags: ruby, button, twitter, rubygems, watir

I'm trying to locate the twitter login button using a gem called Watir.

This is the button markup:

```
<button type="submit" class="submit EdgeButton EdgeButton--primary EdgeButtom--medium">Log in</button>
```

This is my code:

```
# Click Login Button
browser.button(:class => ['submit' 'EdgeButton' 'EdgeButton--primary' 'EdgeButtom--medium'],:tag_name=>"button").click
```

I receive this error:

> Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: timed out after 30 seconds, > waiting for Watir::Button: located: false; > {:class=>["submitEdgeButtonEdgeButton--primaryEdgeButtom--medium"], > :tag_name=>"button"}> to be located; Maybe look in an iframe?> > C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.10.3/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:664:in > `rescue in element_call' > C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.10.3/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:680:in >`element_call' > C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.10.3/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:125:in > `click' C:/Users/bnbih/Desktop/ig_bot/auto_follow_tw.rb:34:in`start' > C:/Users/bnbih/Desktop/ig_bot/auto_follow_tw.rb:77:in `<top > (required)>' > C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/ocra-1.3.10/bin/ocra:1211:in >`load' > C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/ocra-1.3.10/bin/ocra:1211:in > `<top (required)>' C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/ocra:23:in`load' > C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/ocra:23:in `'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can locate using text, write the following code,

```
browser.button(text: 'Log in').click
```

If you still want to use class locator then

```
b.button(class: 'submit EdgeButton EdgeButton--primary EdgeButtom--medium').click
```

Comment: You should use an Array if you are trying to locate an element using multiple classes.

Comment: @titusfortner okay.

Answer (score 2):

You have the classes in an array, but do not have commas separating the Strings. The code perceives it to be an array with one long string unless you have the commas.

```
b.button(class: ['submit', 'EdgeButton', 'EdgeButton--primary', 'EdgeButtom--medium']).click
```